# Use One Cell to Add Values to a Named Range

Tags: dropdown, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges

We are trying to allow the end-user of this Google spreadsheet to be able to add values to a Named Range without accessing said range. (Sorting it will be a q for a later date)

In other words, let's say that we have a list of Suppliers that we purchase parts from, and that list resides on 'SheetLists' in cells A1 to A119.

To make that list easier for later use, we made it into a Named Range and named it "list1Supplier".

We then use that "Named Range" throughout the Workbook in drop-down lists. Each of the drop-down lists reference the "Named Range" and NOT cells A1 to A119.

We also realized that, should we begin using a new Supplier, the list could grow. So we changed the Named Range reference to cells A1:A, thus including the entire A column.

Now, as expected, one of the end users begins using a new Supplier. The LAST thing we would EVER want is for them to have to figure out how to add said Supplier to the end of that list MANUALLY... right!?!?

I've googled this for hours and have found NOTHING except ONE using VBA. And unless someone has a REALLY easy to follow How-To on VBA basics, I'd like to try this route first...

As always, ANY and ALL help is GREATLY appreciated!

DG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you just don't create a live form?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNMdjVxAEYY

Best

Comment: Sebastian Malinski, you are now the smartest person I know! Thanks to your suggestion, that is EXACTLY what I am doing! Thanks!!!